# php compare YYYY-mm-dd strings in php

Tags: php, date

I have run across php code the compares dates in YYYY-mm-dd format as strings. Does this work? It seems to work in simple cases, but I am not sure it makes sense to compare them as strings.

```
<?php
$today = '2013-02-11';
$start_date = '2013-02-11';
$end_date = '2013-02-12';
$on_promo = (($start_date <= $today) && ($end_date >= $today));

if ($on_promo)
{
    echo 'ON promo';
}
else
{
    echo 'OFF promo';
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually doing `date('2013-02-11');` is a bit redundant. `var_dump(date('2013-02-11'))` produces `string(10) "2013-02-11"`. Essentially you're just comparing strings.

Comment: I am just puzzled on why it was working.

Comment: I just fixed the code I had

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing strings in PHP using greater than or less than, it compares them in alphabetical order.

Alphabetically `2013-02-10` comes before `2013-02-13`

If we have:

```
$date1 = '2013-02-10';
$date2 = '2013-02-13';
var_dump($date2 > $date1); // produces true

var_dump('apple' > 'banana'); // produces false
```

However, note that if the strings are both numerical, it will cast them both to integers

```
var_dump('11' > '101'); // produces false
var_dump('a11' > 'a101'); // produces true
var_dump('11a' > '101a'); // produces true
```

Therefore if using the format `YYYY-MM-DD` you can compare two dates perfectly fine, however I really don't recommend relying on this. Someone might throw in a date like `2013-2-11` (note the month doesn't have the leading `0`) and it will completely throw off the logic. It is much better to take John Conde's suggestion and use `DateTime`

Answer (score 4):

You're *soooooo* close. Just use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). It's perfect for this;

```
<?php
$today      = new DateTime('2013-02-11');
$start_date = new DateTime('2013-02-11');
$end_date   = new DateTime('2013-02-12');
$on_promo   = (($start_date <= $today) && ($end_date >= $today));

if ($on_promo)
{
    echo 'ON promo';
}
else
{
    echo 'OFF promo';
}
?>
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FUUNrZ)

Answer (score 1):

use `strtotime` instead of comparing dates as strings

```
<?php
$today = date('U');
$start_date = strtotime('2013-02-11');
$end_date = strtotime('2013-02-12');
$on_promo = (($start_date <= $today) && ($end_date >= $today));

if ($on_promo)
{
    echo 'ON promo';
}
else
{
    echo 'OFF promo';
}
?>
```

Comment: I think `strtotime` has better performance than `DateTime` object for comparison case.